# How to understand the spin structures on $T^d$ and $\mathbb{RP}^d$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, projective-space, spin-geometry

How to understand the spin structures on $T^d$ and $\mathbf{RP}^d$?

1. We know that $H_1(T^d,\mathbb{Z}_2)=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^d$.

- It looks that there are $2^d$ choices on 1-cycle of $T^d$.
- But it seems like people say there are two kinds of spin structures: even and odd. How do we obtain them from $H_1(T^d,\mathbb{Z}_2)=(\mathbb{Z}_2)^d$?

2. We know that $H_1(\mathbf{RP}^d,\mathbb{Z}_2)= \mathbb{Z}_2$.

- Are there two kinds of spin structures for $\mathbf{RP}^d$? How to understand them?
- If $\mathbf{RP}^d$ is oriented ($d$ odd), can we exchange the two spin structures?
- If $\mathbf{RP}^d$ is unoriented ($d$ even), can we exchange the two spin structures?

Comment: How do you define spin structures on a non-orientable manifold? More generally how do you define a spin structure if $w_2(M)\neq 0$?

Comment: In any case, the only projective spaces to consider are $\mathbb{R}P^{4n-1}$ which have $w_1=w_2=0$. As you point out in this case there are two spin structures. I don't know how to describe them nicely. The space $\mathbb{R}P^{4n-1}$ admits an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, but I don't know how it interacts with the spin structures.

Comment: On the other hand $T^n$ is a Lie group so it is parallelisable and you are describing spin structure on the trivial bundle.

Comment: thanks for the comment!

Comment: Can you say more about the space ℝ4−1 admits an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism? Does that orientation-reversing diffeomorphism reverse the two spin structures?

Comment: If I recall, it is induced by the complex conjugation on $\mathbb{R}^{4n}\cong\mathbb{C}^{2n}$. There is a good chance it might interchange the spin structures. Your best bet is to ask someone smarter than me. This trick normally works for me, at least ;).